# Finding roots of $4^x+6^x=9^x$ by hand

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f(x)=4^x+6^x-9^x$ is such that $f(0)=1>0, f(1)=1>0, f(2)=-29$ and next $g(x)=(4/9)^x+(6/9)^x-1 \implies f'(x)<0$ for all real values of $x$. So $g(x)$ being monotonic the equation
$$4^x+6^x=9^x$$ has exactly one real solution. The question is whether this real root can be found analytically by hand.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. You can search [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%244%5Ex%2B6%5Ex%3D9%5Ex%24).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Divide by $4^x$ and let $X=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x$.